# js to resize image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function carousel_bg(id) {
    var bgimgs = ['1920x625_Sonata_homepage_image.jpg', '1920x625_Equus_homepage_image.jpg', '5_home_hero_1920x625_CF_background.jpg']; // add images here..               
    var img = bgimgs[id];
    var cnt = 3; // change this number when adding images..                
    $('#body').css("background-image", "url(http://www.pitstopmotors.com.ph/images/" + img + ")");
    id = id + 1;
    if (id == cnt) id = 0;
    setTimeout("carousel_bg(" + id + ")", 10000);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    carousel_bg(0);
});
</script>
</head>
  <body id="body">
```

I'm using the code above to have my background as a carousel however the images don't perfectly. Can anyone help me add a function to the script that will allow me to add these styles  width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0; Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Instead of hardcoding `cnt=3` you can get the array length. You cannot set the position of background image to absolute.

```
 function carousel_bg(id) {
    var bgimgs = ['bg_img1.jpg']; // add images here.. 
    var img = bgimgs[id]; 
    var cnt =        bgimgs.length; // made it dynamic 
    $('#main').css({
        "background-image": "url(http://www.pitstopmotors.com.ph/images/" + img + ")",
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": "0px",
        "left": "0px"}); 

    id = id + 1; 
    if (id==cnt) 
      id = 0;

    setTimeout("carousel_bg("+id+")", 10000); 
} 

$(document).ready(function() { carousel_bg(0); });
```

Comment: I think he might want to add the position css to the `#body` element. You'll notice the `#`, which means it isn't the actual body but probably a div with an id "body".

Comment: @Peter - I see, all the way I was thinking its a body tag didnt look at # :)

Comment: thanks for the help, however it doesn't work :[ the body div on mines is actualy #main i just copy pasted the code directly from another site.

Comment: function carousel_bg(id) {
                var bgimgs = [ 'bg_img1.jpg' ]; // add images here..
                var img = bgimgs[id];
                var cnt = bgimgs.length; // made it dynamic

                $('#main').css("backgroundImag: "url("+img+")", 
    backgroundPosition: "0px 0px" });

                id = id + 1;
                if (id==cnt) id = 0;

                setTimeout("carousel_bg("+id+")", 10000);
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
                carousel_bg(0);     
        }); // this is my actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Just extend this line where you add the css to the `#body` element:

```
$('#body').css({
"background-image": "url(http://www.pitstopmotors.com.ph/images/" + img + ")",
"position": "absolute",
"top": 0,
"left": 0});
```

Comment: well the background image is working again but now it actually made it worse ._. the rest of my divs are out of place. i'm also using the 960 css framework would that have to do something wit it?

Comment: @jay I can't really tell you why unless I see the css for the other divs

Comment: well i'm pretty sure its the 960 css framework that causes the other divs to be out of place, however the background image still doesn't resize correctly. i've made all my bg images with the size 1600px by 1000px. resizing it in photoshop wont be a problem however i want the bg image to be universal to all resolutions.